# How to download CSV using REST API?

Tags: export-to-csv, servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

Here's a REST API that I am trying for downloading data as CSV file.

```
(function process(/*RESTAPIRequest*/ request, /*RESTAPIResponse*/ response) {

    var data = '\n'; // workaround to separate <xml> start tag on first line
    data += 'Firstname,Lastname,Username' + '\n';
    data += 'Nikhil,vartak,niksofteng' + '\n';
    data += 'Unknown,person,anonymous' + '\n';

    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=Xyz.csv");
    response.setContentType("text/csv");
    response.setBody({'data':data});

})(request, response);
```

According to [docs](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/istanbul-servicenow-platform/page/app-store/dev_portal/API_reference/ScriptableServiceResponseBuilder/reference/r_SSRB-setBody_Object.html) `setBody` requires a JS object and thus if I just pass `data` variable I get error stating that data cannot be parsed into `ScriptableObject`.

So with the current code I get below response:

```
{
  "result": {
    "data": "\nFirstname,Lastname,Username\nNikhil,vartak,niksofteng\nUnknown,person,anonymous\n"
  }
}
```

And the generated CSV looks like this:

[image]

Any idea how to get rid of that XML markup on 1st and 5th line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The setBody method expects a Javascript object which it is then going to serialize to JSON or XML based on what the client tells it do via Accept header.

In your case you want to produce your own serialized format: CSV. So instead of using the setBody method, use the stream writer interface to directly write to the response stream.

```
response.setContentType("text/csv");
response.setStatus(200);
var writer = response.getStreamWriter();

writer.write('Firstname,Lastname,Username\n');
writer.write('Nikhil,vartak,niksofteng\n');
```

etc.

Note you will have to handle all the details of CSV format yourself, including properly encoding any special characters like if you want a field to contain a comma like "Nik,hil".

Cheers,

Silas

Comment: Thanks Silas. One thing here - the method name is `setStatus`. Also this needs to be set explicitly else things wont work for large data as [this post](https://community.servicenow.com/community/develop/developer-relations/blog/2017/03/31/scripted-rest-api-stream-writers-and-http-status) explains. Mentioned for others with similar problem in future.